# How to store the value of drop down and text box in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to store the default shown option of a drop down in a variable for further examination and I don't know how to do that.
Similarly for text field (Store the value in a variable)
I am able to select using

```
select from list by index  ${transactionType_dropdown_xpath}  4
```

but if I say

```
${txnType}=  select from list by index  ${transactionType_dropdown_xpath}  4
```

and `log to console ${txnType}`, it is printing **None**

All I want is:

Before selecting the drop down, store the currently displayed value in a variable

Before entering text in a text field, store the currently displayed value in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `Select From List By Index` does not return anything (it just does the action), thus you get the value `None` in the variable.

To get the currently selected label - the text for the option - use the keyword [`Get Selected List Label`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Selected%20List%20Label); a similar one, but with different purpose is `Get Selected List Value` - it will return the "value" attribute of the html element, the thing the form will send when submitted (you probably want the former).

And to get the text you've entered in an input field - if I understand your last question correctly, you need to get the property of its `value` attribute, by the keyword [`Get Element Attribute`](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute):

```
${the text}=    Get Element Attribute    xpath=//your/locator/here    value
# it has a shortcut - Get Value - that does precisely the same
${the text}=    Get Value    xpath=//your/locator/here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getText`](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Text) it returns text of given xpath, pass the xpath locator of the list and store it in the variable.